# High CPU-consuming Mysql request with php

Tags: php, mysql, cpu

I'm currently benching all my php services for an iOS app.
One of them appears to consume all my 3 cpu cores really fast (while no other do).
This service fetches the 51 nearest "bubbles" (bulles) to where the user actually is.
Here is my php :

```
$sql="SELECT *, get_distance('$latitude','$longitude',latitude,longitude) AS proximite
FROM bulles INNER JOIN
(SELECT userId, userFirstName, userLastName, userName, userPictureUrl from user) AS users
ON bulles.auteur = users.userId
INNER JOIN interests
ON bulles.interet1 = interests.id
WHERE auteur = '$userID'
OR auteur
IN (
    SELECT followedId
    FROM following
    WHERE followerId = '$userID'
)
ORDER BY proximite
LIMIT 51";
```

and here is my stored function "get_distance" :

```
FUNCTION `get_distance`(lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE) RETURNS double
BEGIN
    DECLARE rlo1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rlo2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlo DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dla DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;

    SET rlo1 = RADIANS(lng1);
    SET rla1 = RADIANS(lat1);
    SET rlo2 = RADIANS(lng2);
    SET rla2 = RADIANS(lat2);
    SET dlo = (rlo2 - rlo1) / 2;
    SET dla = (rla2 - rla1) / 2;
    SET a = SIN(dla) * SIN(dla) + COS(rla1) * COS(rla2) * SIN(dlo) * SIN(dlo);
    RETURN (6378137 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1 - a)));
END
```

10 of this service request per second saturates the cpu.
I've had problems before with INNER JOIN statements, so maybe it comes from there ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: Start by using `EXPLAIN` before your `SELECT` and check the output or post it here.

Comment: A three-level nested join, a sub-select, and a custom function used in the outmost table, and you're wondering why it's slow? You might want to look into PostGresQL + PostGIS, which can move the location lookup into the DB, and presumably optimize it (indexes, etc)

Comment: IIRC latest version of MySQL has geospatial features, though I've not looked at them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 'IN' is very inefficient (while a nice construct) as the query is reprocessed for every single row. i.e.

```
IN (
    SELECT followedId
    FROM following
    WHERE followerId = '$userID'
)
```

Replace it with a table in the FROM clause. e.g.:

```
...FROM ( SELECT followedId FROM following WHERE followerId = '$userID') AS whatever 
(then in the WHERE put ) OR auteur = whatever.followedId...
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks !
While 10 requests/second was saturating the cpu, now 25 stays below 40%.